# Can a NMOS transistor be used as a Current Controlled Voltage Source?

Tags: transistors, nmos

Assuming an NMOS transistor is in saturation. Can you apply a current \$I_{DS}\$, resulting in an output gate-source voltage (\$V_{GS}\$)?

Answer (score 3):

The gate is isolated so by itself it cannot generate a voltage. An NMOS only has a causal relation from Vgs to Ids, not the reverse.

You can however connect gate to drain (NMOS diode) and inject a drain current. Then the NMOS will be insaturation (why ?) and the Vgs will be the value correspinding to the Id you injected

This principle is used in current mirrors.

Answer (score 2):

If the transistor is in saturation there is already a current Ids that is non-zero. There will be some particular voltage on the gate. Let's assume it is open and we are measuring the voltage with a very good voltmeter that does not draw significant current from the gate.

The gate appears like a couple of series capacitors- one to the source and one to the drain. If you change the current Ids, then the voltage Vds will change and some (usually a small amount) of that voltage change will appear on the gate. The gate voltage change will *reduce* the Vds change compared to what you'd see if you held the gate at a constant voltage with a voltage source.

In practice the capacitances are fairly small (nF or pF) so leakage will change the voltage pretty quickly- it's not a useful voltage source in steady state.